# How to integrate custom view with TabBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitabbar

Well I wish there was some tutorial anywhere or any of the O'Reily Cookbooks would explain this but everyone only ever talks about using UITabBarController.

What I need in my app however is a custom view (basic UIViewController) with a NavigationBar (just for the title bar and a 'Done' button) and a TabBar in it.

The question is: How do I integrate the TabBar and connect views to each bar button (and add more bar buttons)? Can this only be done programmatically or is it possible in Storyboard? And which class needs to be the TabBarDelegate (I suppose my custom UIViewController)?

Does anyone know of a good guide for this or provide me with some hints?

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**:

I decided to simply check in the TabBarDelegate for the tabBar.selectedItem.tag and instantiate a sub view accordingly from the storyboard and add it into a ContainerView that is sandwiched between my nav bar and the tab bar at the bottom. This works so far (although I'm not sure if there's not a better approach) but now I'm facing a different problem:

When a sub view is loaded into the ContainerView the whole tab bar disappears. Does somebody know why this happens?

Comment: Check, if tab bar is nil. Check, if tab bar superview is nil.

Comment: Check. They are both not nil. I suspect it has to do with AutoLayout. I created a new ticket for this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281013/auto-layout-acting-strange-with-wany-hany

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to crate Tab Bar Controller app with Storyboard. Apple even provides a snippet :) When creating a new project, just select iOS -> Application -> Tabbed Application.

Also, here is a pretty good tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhsHtd6rAiQ.

Comment: Errm, did you read my description above? The Tabbed Application template uses a ready-made TabBarController. But that's not what I need.

Comment: So the Tab Bar is not a problem? Then you should name your question "How to add navigation bar to view controller".

Comment: The difference here is between TabBar (placed in my case in a UIViewController) and a TabBarController.  These two are different components.

Comment: Then answer is, that this can be done programmatically, yes. Can't tell anything about storyboard.

Comment: Hey @kelin I integrated it meanwhile with code. Do you have any idea about why the tab bar would disappear (see update note above)?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the original issue myself by creating a Xib with UIViewController in it and place a UITabBar and a UIView as container for subviews. Then load the xib with NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed() and create Xibs for the sub views that should be loaded and load these with loadNibNamed() and add them with viewContainer.addSubview().